# add new column using code first approach in mvc 4 on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

My existing model in code first approach

```
public class student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

I have to add two more column in this student table, hence I updated it like this

```
public class student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string std { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to lose the existing student table. How can I add this column on production server using code first approach

Please help .

Comment: It won't if you have migrations enabled and don't have an initializer that drops and recreates your database. Always safe to back it up first. I also recommend [scripting](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) the update to production.

Answer (score 0):

You will not lose existing student table its make a problem when you want add a column that is not null so in that situation you must set default value for it.
Update your Model in console manger run Add-Migration command with setting a name.

Than run Update-Database Command.

PM> Add-Migration intial123

PM> Update-Database  -Verbose

Answer (score 0):

Why will you lose existing table in production? Update your entity model by adding extra columns. Add code first migration, and deploy it in production. Your existing table will be as it is with extra columns added, unless you have set `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;`

Comment: my existing data will lost in student table ?